# Log entries on Apple Watch during the day and display later

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watch

I'm currently developing an Apple Watch app which uses Background tasks. For some reason, after around 6 hours, I'm having issues with those tasks.

In order to debug this, I'd like my Watch Extension to Log some statements during the day and accessing some kind of log later from my PC. From what I understand reading the documentation, I can only see Apple Watch Log statments when attached to the debugger which is not valid in my case.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I can do here?

I was actually already thinking about creating a tableview in my watch app and show my custom log, but I'm sure there is an easier way.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want the logs recorded also when the watch is not connected to the iPhone?

Comment: That would be very desirable, but it's not must-have for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t understand yet exactly what you are trying to do, but anyway:
I assume you create some kind of strings on the watch that describe unusual situations.

On the watch:
You could create an array of such strings, and append a new string when required.
You could then monitor if communication with the iPhone is possible.
Either it is possible at the time when a new string is added, or you could receive a notification when it is possible.
In both cases, you could send the whole dictionary (depending on its size) as a direct message or as a file to the iPhone.

On the iPhone:
When a direct message with this dictionary arrives, simply overwrite a previous version.
So, latest when your watch is close to the iPhone, you will have the complete logs on the iPhone app.
At appropriate times, you could send them via email to your Mac.

I am not sure if this a feasible approach for you.

Comment: Hi Reinhard, thanks a lot for this input. I was assuming that iOS has some kind of default log file functionality for Apps which I could use on Apple Watch to make things simple. I will implement a system on my own now that I understand there isn't something available already.

BTW I checked your profile and wow, what a coincidence, I'm from Heidelberg too and developing iOS for fun as well :)

Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, I don't know if there is a simpler solution. But my approach would allow you to get the logs in "real time" whenever your watch is connected to your iPhone.

Comment: Yeah, I was just hoping for a file to dump my strings but I'll just use an array which I'll send as message

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the method suggested by Reinhard, you can also collect full logs by either:

1. Connecting your phone to your Mac when XCode is running and opening Console app on the Mac - you should see your Apple Watch there. It won't allow you to collect historical data though.
2. Running sysdiagnose profile that will collect some historical data as well: https://download.developer.apple.com/iOS/watchOS_Logs/sysdiagnose_Logging_Instructions.pdf

A few other observations based on my experience:

1. Background refresh tasks usually are pretty reliable, unless you invoke them more than 4 times an hour. However, WatchOS may stop running your background tasks altogether when the battery drops below 10%, and there seems to be some throttling between 10 and 20 percent charge.
2. WatchOS 5.0.1 seems to have some instability in handling background URL sessions. Sometimes it just stops downloading data without producing any errors, even if timeout for resource is exceeded. Then it just starts working again. Sometimes killing "stuck" download tasks at the next background refresh helps to get it running normally again, but not always. Again, this behavior started with 5.0.1 (or maybe 5.0).
3. Logging via Console may not give you all log statements. It is working more reliably now, and I don't know if upgrading to Mojave helped, or it's a coincidence, but it used to drop some log statements that should've been there.